# socket.io: Bad Request, connecting from outside

Tags: node.js, socket.io, bad-request

I installed node.js and the module socket.io (http://socket.io).
The chat example of socket.io works just fine for me, typing in my
browser

```
http://localhost:3000
```

But I cannot get anything to work using another IP, eventhough the
server listens on all interfaces (i.e. 0.0.0.0). My ethernet
interface has the address 192.168.1.1, typing in my browser

```
http://192.168.1.1:3000
```

I get the chat webpage, but my Firebug (still on the same computer)
says:

```
NetworkError: 400 Bad Request
```

and the websocket connection is not established. The result is, that I
cannot reach my websockets from the outside, whatever code I write.

I use node v0.6.12, firefox 11.0, Ubuntu 11.10.

Questions:

1) Can anybody confirm this error?

2) How can I reach a websocket from another computer than localhost?

3) Is there any socket.io example where the connection works from the outside on a normal ubuntu installation?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Share your code.
are you using express??
use --> `app.listen(3000);`

Comment: install socket.io using `npm install socket.io`, the code is in `node_modules/socket.io/examples/chat`, the code uses express.

Answer (score 0):

**Solved: disable proxy in Firefox**

Apparently my Ubuntu installation started [ziproxy](http://ziproxy.sourceforge.net/) automatically
and configuered Firefox to use it. Setting Firefox to "no proxy"
solved the problem. Now I can connect to my websockets from the
outside.